# First Byte Time scores F

Tags: wordpress, performance, server, hosting, wait

I recently purchased a new theme and installed wordpress on my GoDaddy hosting account for my portfolio.  I am still working on it, but as of right now I sometimes get page load speeds of 10-20seconds, and others 2 seconds (usually after the page has been cached). I have done all that I believe I can (without breaking the site) to optimize my performance speed (reducing image sizing, using a free CDN, using W3 Total Cache, etc).

It seems that my main issue is this 'TTFB' wait time I get whenever I go to a new page that hasn't been cached yet.  How I can fix this? Is it the theme's fault?  Do I NEED to switch hosting providers?  I really don't want to go through the hassle of doing that and paying So much more just to have less than optimal results.  I am new to this.

My testing site:
http://test.ninamariephotography.com/

See my Web Page Results here:
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/161111_9W_WF0/

Thank you in advance to anyone for your help:)

Comment: Your page is .. large, multiple images over 3MiB, google recommends savings of 30MiB+ See https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://test.ninamariephotography.com/

Comment: Maybe you should ask your hosting provider why the first byte time is slow. I just retried and the loading time was like really good for this extremly high amount of images (http://www.webpagetest.org/result/161111_H0_YAJ/).

If requests are usually cached and the 10 seconds waiting is only on every 1 of 1000 requests that should be o.k.

Answer (score 1):

*Time To First Byte* should depend on geography. I don't think that's your problem. I reran your test and got a `B`.

I think the issue is your hosting is a tiny shared instance, and you're serving static files. Here are some ideas to speed things up.

- Serve images using an image-serving service. Check out [imgix](https://www.imgix.com/) which is $3/m. It could help in unexpected ways serving images off an external domain depending on HTTP protocol version and browser version, and how connections are shared.
- Try lossy compression. You lose some image detail, but you also lose some file size. Check out [compressor.io](https://compressor.io/compress) for an easy tool.
- Concatenate and minify scripts. You have a number of little javascript files that load individually. Consider joining them together and minifying. I don't know the tool chain for Wordpress, perhaps there's a setting?

If none of that helps, you should experiment with different a hosting choice.